# perl - universal operator overload

Tags: perl, overloading, operator-keyword

I have an idea for perl, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement it.

The idea is to have new versions of every operator which consider the undefined value as the identity of that operation. For example:

```
$a = undef + 5;     # undef treated as 0, so $a = 5
$a = undef . "foo"; # undef treated as '', so $a = foo
$a = undef && 1;    # undef treated as false, $a = true
```

and so forth.

ideally, this would be in the language as a pragma, or something.

```
use operators::awesome;
```

However, I would be satisfied if I could implement this special logic myself, and then invoke it where needed:

```
use My::Operators;
```

The problem is that if I say "use overload" inside My::Operators only affects objects blessed into My::Operators.

So the question is: is there a way (with "use overoad" or otherwise) to do a "universal operator overload" - which would be called for all operations, not just operations on blessed scalars.

If not - who thinks this would be a great idea !? It would save me a TON of this kind of code

```
if($object && $object{value} && $object{value} == 15)

replace with

if($object{value} == 15)  ## the special "is-equal-to" operator
```

Comment: This pragma already exists. It is called `no warnings`;

Comment: I`m assuming you meant to say `$object->{value}` instead of `$object{value}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those operations already work the way you expect them to:

- In the context of numbers, `undef` is `0`.
- In the context of strings, `undef` is the empty string `''`.
- In the context of booleans, `undef` is `0`.

If you `use warnings`, then perl will let you know that the value is uninitialized, but it will still work just fine.

Comment: short, and to the point. Thanks! I should've thought of this.

Answer (score 6):

It is *possible*. It would take a lot of work, but you could write an "op checker" that replaces the ops for `&&` with custom op that's your reimplementation of `&&`.

But it would be a very bad idea. For starters,

```
if ($a && $b) {
   ...
}
```

would stop being equivalent to

```
if ($a) {
   if ($b) {
      ...
   }
}
```

To take your own example,

```
if ($object && $object{value} && $object{value} == 15) {
   ...
}
```

With your requested model, it would have to be written

```
if ($object{value}) { if ($object{value} == 15) {
   ...
}}
```

You actually want the exact opposite of what you asked for. You actually want the current behaviour. Without your module, you can write:

```
if ($object{value} && $object{value} == 15) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
no warnings 'uninitialized';
if ($object{value} == 15) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (($object{value} // 0) == 15) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: you're right that no warnings 'uninitialized' does MOST of what I'm talking about. Care to give some more details about the "custom op checker" idea though? I don't know how perl allows you to hook operators between, say, two literal numbers.

Comment: @Todd Freed, The op checker visits every op, and can replace them with others. This is how [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) (the module) works.

Comment: the autovivification module appears to be implemented entirely in xs. So I guess you can't overload operators in this sense in pure-perl?

Comment: @Todd Freed, "Pure Perl" just means you're using someone else's XS, so you're asking if someone has exposed all the necessary parts of the API to the Perl symbol table. I don't know. Why are you still trying to fill this insane goal of yours when all it does it make the code you have to write more complicated?

Comment: You claim this is possible but you won't say HOW. Let me boil it down for you. "my $a = 5 + 5" how do you overload the plus operator in this case? I do not believe 'use overload' can do it. I want to know because I want to know, not necessarily because I intend to rewrite any code to use this.

Comment: @Todd Freed, I did say how: Use the op checker to replace add opcodes with your own opcode. I even told you how to use the op checker: Look at the [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification).

Comment: @ikegami : Would anything change if you used `||` instead of `//` in your last example?

Comment: @Zaid, The only difference is that `||` would hide a warning if `$object{value}` is an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

As mob said, your pragma already exists.  It's spelled `no warnings 'uninitialized';`.  Perl already treats `undef` as either 0 or the empty string (depending on context).  This just suppresses the warning you usually get (assuming you have warnings turned on, which you should).

If you want to create a package that does this automatically, you can:

```
package operators::awesome;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub import {
  warnings->unimport('uninitialized');
}
```

Now `use operators::awesome;` will turn off warnings about uninitialized values.

Here's a fancier version of `import` that turns on strict and warnings, but turns off warnings about uninitialized values:

```
sub import {
  strict->import;
  warnings->import;
  warnings->unimport('uninitialized');
}
```

Comment: How is this different from just using `no warnings 'uninitialized'`?

Comment: @TLP, it isn't.  I was just pointing out that you can write a package that does the equivalent of `no warnings 'uninitialized'` for you.  It can also do other things, like turn on strict and other warnings.  It could even export functions if you want, although that would be more complicated.

Comment: @ikegami, I just noticed his description is inconsistent.  He says "undef treated as false, $a = true", but false && true is false, not true.